# Using $first and $last with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using an ng-repeat that can iterate over one record or hundreds. I am also using the $first and $last where my record is displayed. Is there a simple way to suppress the $first and $last is the ng-repeat is only iterating over 5 or less records.
My issue is if a user searches thru our database and returns only one record, the record will have links that are associated with the $first and $last and I want to suppress them if there are 5 or less records returned.

Comment: You can just check the length of the array as an additional condition

Comment: By using something like ng-class="{'class': $first && xx.length > 5}"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-if` conditionals or different iteration behavior depending on how many records you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-if` on your `ng-repeat` element:

```
ng-repeat="record in records" ng-if="records.length > 5 || !$first && !$last"
```

I am not quite sure what your question is: This will show the first and last record if the given array length is bigger than 5.

Comment: Thanks. I used ng-if="$index > 5 && $last" and got what I needed